# Must a hierarchical finite state machine only 'exist' in a leaf state?

Tags: design-patterns, c++, uml

With hierarchical state machines, and their UML state chart counterparts, all the references I've found so far suggest that an active state must be a leaf state.

I've looked at Samek, and papers that implement HFSMs in C++. Most suggest any transition to a composite (read parent) state must be followed by successive initial transitions to a leaf state.

Firstly, is this in the definition?

Given that these 'program by difference', surely a composite state could have all we need for an actual state!?

Comment: Is this what you've been reading: [who moved my state?](http://www.drdobbs.com/who-moved-my-state/184401643)

Comment: My main reference is Miro Samek's book 'Practical UML Statecharts in C/C++', 2nd ed. He has many articles in journals, many of which are on his site: http://www.state-machine.com/doc/articles.html.

Many of the implementation papers reference this work, eg Babitsky, Heinzmann,...

I also have a few of the well known UML books.

Answer (score 4):

You would expect an active, single, flat state machine to always be in exactly one state.

A hierarchical statechart, as in with [Harel statecharts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_diagram#Harel_statechart), (from which some of UML is derived) is effectively a  composition of two or more independent statecharts, that leaves the original, individual statecharts intact interconnecting them rather than flattening all the compositions into a single, (potentially much) larger, flat statechart.

Similar -- that we expect to find the individual state machines in one state -- still holds true for these individual statecharts even when combined in hierarchy, *except* that the hierarchical mechanism allows for conjunction (orthogonal AND-state) and disjunction (OR-state): here the significance meaning some of the composed state machines may or may not be active.

From [UML State machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML_state_machine)

> > If a system is in the nested state, ... (called the substate), it also (implicitly) is in the surrounding state ... (called the superstate).

In other words, and perhaps stated from the other direction, when an superstate is active that has substate, then the substate is also active, and in some particular state.  This applies recursively, which is maybe why it looks like what is active is always leaf state.

> Most suggest any transition to a composite (read parent) state must be followed by successive initial transitions to a leaf state.

Note that in the code you describe, it appears that transition to a new superstate is followed by a transition in substate, however, these two together need to appear to any external observer as if they both happened atomically.  It would be invalid to the abstraction of hierarchical state machines to reveal, to users of the abstraction, the in-between situation of being in the superstate but not (yet) in any substate.

---

To your questions:

> Firstly, is this in the definition?

Yes.  You can look at it from superstate to substate (or vice versa): when a superstate becomes active, its substate becomes active.

> surely a composite state could have all we need for an actual state!?

Yes, sort of, but only in and of itself and at that level, which is to say if state had no substate (but then it wouldn't be a composite).

And, so the real answer is no, it is not sufficient (describing composite state is not all we need to properly describe the state machine's state) in the presence of substate (nested state machines) for active superstates (composites), as their substates are active and as well need to be in some state valid for the child (e.g. even of only in their initial state).

Comment: Erik, you wrote "*when a superstate becomes active, its substate becomes active*".  Is this a requirement that's defined somewhere?  What kind of consideration would drive this requirement this way?  I can envision an implementation which allows an HSM to exist only in leaf state.  I can [just as well] envision an implementation which allows an HSM to exist in a parent state; why not?  [Basically, I'm repeating the O.P.'s question.  I've had this type of question in mind for a long time myself.]

Comment: It is just a matter of semantics as to whether we consider a superstate to be also active when one of its substates is active.  This is typically done when taking the point of view that hierarchical state machines are simply compositions of non-hierarchical state machines -- thus a parent level state machine is in some state, when a child level state machine is in a sub-state.

Comment: However, when considering the child states, there is no notion of the parent state being active, while none of the child states are active.  Thus, to the point of view of composed state machines, the parent state alone is not its own state independent of any of its child states.  So, with composed hierarchy, when a parent is in the active state, one of its children is also active.  Thus, we can certainly consider, from a larger point of view, only leaf states.

Comment: "*No. Not generally. May depend on specific HSM implementation.*" is the answer to the O.P.'s question.